# IP Address Restrictions Other Than Profile-Based?

Tags: profile, user, login, crud

We have about 6 users at our company who need a similar set of CRUD permissions against our Salesforce org.

1 of those users is employed in a lesser capacity than the other 5 and therefore shouldn't be allowed to access our Salesforce org from home.

I've already developed a Profile for the 5 users that fits what they need to do in our Salesforce org perfectly.

I've been asked to make the 6th user "just like the other 5, but not able to work from off-site."

Although duplicating a profile is easy, keeping similar profiles' CRUD permissions in sync over time is a nightmare.

If there's any way to just have 1 profile, but give one of its users additional IP address (and possibly work-hours) restrictions, I'd like to know about it!

Comment: You can vote on [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000lALUAA2), and [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ksd2AAA) to allow IP restrictions based on Permission sets.

Comment: Aren't "Permission Sets" for expanding people's access, not restricting it, though?  If so, I doubt Salesforce would ever implement these ideas at face value even if they got enough votes (which they seem pretty far from).  [Then again, I suppose one could just lock down the profile & expand access with a Permission Set if Permission Sets could handle IP ranges.]  Upvoting ... but am I really stuck creating duplicate profiles?  The comments on those ideas are pretty depressing...looks like the answer might be "yes."

Comment: Even if the idea isn't implemented with permission sets, it shows Salesforce that there is a demand for a certain feature.

Comment: Yup, upvoted to help show the demand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have assign IP restrictions through Permission sets (or) Workflows or any other ways.

For your problem you have to assign a separate profile for the user is only the way.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a blog on how to do this with a Login Flow... It will take a bit of work to build, but it will solve your scenario.  You can only assign that one User to the IP Addresses and leave everyone else off (so they don't have a 'restriction')... let me know if you need more of a push in the right direction than this post.

https://salesforcesidekick.com/2015/10/18/user-management-ip-address-validation-andor-restriction-by-user/

Comment: Got sidetracked on other projects, but I'll look into this as soon as I can - thanks so much.